# parse error(possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Tags: haskell

I am making calculating 2^(n-1) mod n. I had a problem with Haskell.

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
  |
5 |     | (mod e 2 == 0) = md (mod b*b m) (div e 2) m r
  |     ^
```

But the problem is I don't know what is the problem

```
modf :: Int -> Int
modf n = md 2 (n-1) n r
    where
    md b e m r
    | (mod e 2 == 0) = md (mod b*b m) (div e 2) m r
    | otherwise = md (mod b*b m) (div e 2) m (mod r*b m)
```

Comment: You need to indent the pipe characters (`|`) with at least one space

Comment: Now the error however says that you never defined `r` (which is indeed correct)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that the indentation level of the guards is the same as the `md` function itself). You need to indent it by at least one space:

```
modf :: Int -> Int
modf n = md 2 (n-1) n r
    where
    md b e m r
        | (mod e 2 == 0) = md (mod b*b m) (div e 2) m r
        | otherwise = md (mod b*b m) (div e 2) m (mod r*b m)
```

Now the syntax error has been resolved, but it will raise an error on the fact that you use `r`, but never defined `r`.

We can implement this more elegantly by:

```
import Data.Bits(shiftR)

modf :: Int -> Int
modf m = go 2 (m-1)
    where go k 1 = k
          go k n | even n = go2
                 | otherwise = mod (go2 * k) m
              where go2 = go (mod (k*k) m) (shiftR n 1)
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without `shiftR?`

Comment: @daogom: `shiftR ... 1`, is equivalent here to `div ... 2`. But with that difference that a CPU is usually better in shifting than dividing (some compilers can optimize it)

Comment: You could also use ``n `quot` 2``.